# Application does not run from command prompt but runs with double click ERROR: WERC6F9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

Tags: wpf, windows, registry

I have a WPF application, when double click from it is location it runs - no problems.
When I trying to start the app from command prompt I get an error.

I need to run the app from command prompt (also using startup register)

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WERC6F9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE6F8.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\WERE718.tmp.mdmp

What could be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can help you

This could be because of Path. When you Double click app the required files for the application will there at the current folder hence the application is able to find and load the files required. But if your executing it from different path other than app path, lets say

Your application is present in the location D:\Data\Example.exe. 
And your executing the app from different location Say C:\Program files, now the app will start running from C:\Program files and it'll start searching required files at C:\Program files and some temp locations once it don't find there it'll throws exception

You can do like this

Write a Batch file.first change the current directory to application directory in this case say D:\Data or you can add your application path to path environment variable and use it

Then Invoke the exe

Save the this file and you call this file from where you want

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem, I also would need to run the app at Start Up adding an entry in the register. Do you have an idea how to solve this path issue in the register?

Comment: Instead of specifying the exe path, specify the batch file path. Or you change the working directory of the app Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(<location of your app>), this should be the first line in your code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
I found out that it was due to me using Debug not Release while building my application. The Microsoft .dll-s in the redistributable is for release.